# App blank page in Safari (Invalid regular expression: group specifier name)

Tags: javascript, safari

My app is working in chrome but not in safari.
Here's the code that breaks it

```
export function numberWithCommas(x) {
 return x.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
}
```

Comment: which is the error displayed on the console?

Comment: @dev-cc Error on the console: Invalid regular expression: Invalid group specifier name